# Shortest Common Superstring Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I know this is a well studied problem. However the version I'm trying to implement isn't focused on the usual DNA sequence context, which just has 4 possible letters, but on an hypothetical alien DNA which uses all 26 letters in it's sequences. There also a size constraint on the superstring. Due to this I feel the largest concatenation method might not work.

The implementation that came to mind was a multi-tree like structure. All the permutations of an atomic sequence with each of the other atomic sequences would be computed, then stored in a "childs" vector, then that vector would be cleaned up for redundancies (i.e no point having C if A+B has C as a substring) and less than optimal concatenations (i.e string A + B only include A and B, not other atomic substrings) and sorted for higher number of included atomic strings (smaller size upon tie). Then it'd recursively brute force away at the best candidate with the same method, concatenating it with the atomic strings it didn't include, and trying the following sibling node upon exhaustion. The stop condition would be number of included atomic substrings = number of original atomic substrings - then it'd just spit out the answer right away through a series of return statements)

I'm aware this solution is quite brutish, heavy and skips over the optimal string, however due to the specifications of the problem it feels like a more direct approach. Eventually the valid branches would converge towards a set of answers which would fit the size constraint, so my theory is that by exhausting the best candidate of each branch we'd get there without having to try all the other options. The recursion would be implemented dynamically.

It's being a brain melter, and I was wondering if I should pursue this tree-like implementation, or just modify the well-known solutions so they apply to the problem

EDIT: The problem is for an algorithm class. The test input i'm currently working on has 40 strings ranging from 1 to 49 characters and a maximum answer size of 300. However I'm trying to abstract from the problem and figure out a general solution. The hardest input has 212 strings, some with over 7k characters, and a max answer size of 35k

Comment: I assume you're talking about the [shortest **common** superstring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence_problem). I'm not sure having 26 symbols in the alphabet instead of 4 is that much of an issue.  Also, could you please complete your question with information about the size of your problem? How many strings do you have? What is the length of those strings? What is the size constraint on the superstring? The shortest common superstring problem is NP-hard in general, but depending on the size of your problem, it might be doable.

Comment: Related questions: [More efficient algorithm for shortest superstring search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20071702/more-efficient-algorithm-for-shortest-superstring-search/20074602) and [find the common superstring from given list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966929/find-the-common-superstring-from-given-list-of-strings-in-python)

Comment: @Stef you assume correcly. thanks for the hint. I've added the specifications

Comment: @Stef so yeah, given the fact the input is what it is I feel it'd be faster to try and brute force a key instead of looking for the best possible concatenation - this would result in an absurd number of iterations when the longer inputs start popping up. through my method I'm ensuring i'm only testing strings which haven't been obtained by concatenating other strings, which greatly limits test cases - managed a ~95% redution in the number of candidates after clean up . The branch convergence also checks out although still not properly implemented - just tested it with specific restrictions